# Can this XSL code be changed to fill in a HTML table instead?

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I have this excellent answer to a question provided to me yesterday:

[Selecting specific entries in a for-each loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35063212/selecting-specific-entries-in-a-for-each-loop/35064713?noredirect=1#comment57853568_35064713)

Due to space constraints on the printed page I would like to layout the data in a table instead. Here is an example, modified in Microsoft Expression Web:

[image: Desired output]

So, I would like to take the current XSL code that I am using:

```
<xsl:variable name="AssignHistory" select="document('AssignHistory.xml')"/>
<xsl:variable name="week" select="Date/@NextWeek"/>
<xsl:apply-templates select="$AssignHistory/AssignmentHistory/*[name()=$week]/StudentItems"/>
```

And the template functions:

```
<xsl:template match="StudentItems">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="Item[not((position() - 1) mod 7)]" mode="leader"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Item" mode="leader">
  <xsl:value-of select="Description"/>
  :&#160;
  <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
  <br/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::Item[position() &lt;= 6 and position() mod 2]"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Item">
  <xsl:value-of select="Description"/>
  :&#160;
  <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::Item[1]" mode="follower"/>
  <br/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Item" mode="follower">
  <xsl:text> / </xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
</xsl:template>
```

So, the final table will have either 1, 2 or 3 columns.

If there are 7 items student items in the list, then it has 1 column of content.
If there are 14 items, then items 7 to 14 are shown in the second column.
If there are 21 items, then items 15 to 21 are shown in the third column.

The only other differences are:

1. The first column will has the rows prefixed with the "description" value.
2. There would be a heading row stating the "school" (hardcoded text). Unless there is only 1 column, in which case this row is not needed.

Is it possible to adjust these templates in any way to create this revised output?

Here is some revised XML data to use:

```
    <StudentItems>
        <Item>
            <Name Counsel="9">1</Name>
            <Type>Bible Reading (Main)</Type>
            <Description>Bible Reading</Description>
        </Item>
        <Item Description="Initial Call">
            <Name Counsel="37">2</Name>
            <Type>#1 Student (Main)</Type>
            <Description>Initial Call</Description>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <Name>3</Name>
            <Type>Assistant</Type>
            <Description>Initial Call</Description>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <Name Counsel="48">4</Name>
            <Type>#2 Student (Main)</Type>
            <Description>Return Visit</Description>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <Name>5</Name>
            <Type>Assistant</Type>
            <Description>Return Visit</Description>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <Name Counsel="27">6</Name>
            <Type>#3 Student (Main)</Type>
            <Description>Bible Study</Description>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <Name>7</Name>
            <Type>Assistant</Type>
            <Description>Bible Study</Description>
        </Item>
    </StudentItems>
```

Thank you very much for your kind assistance. I do appreciate it.

I made good progress. I don't know if it is the best way:

```
            <table cellpadding="2">
              <xsl:apply-templates select="$AssignHistory/AssignmentHistory/*[name()=$week]/StudentItems"/>
            </table>
```

and

```
      <xsl:template match="StudentItems">
        <xsl:if test="Item[position() = 1]">
          <xsl:if test="count(Item) = 14">
            <tr>
              <td>
                <b>Main</b>
              </td>
              <td>
                <b>Auxiliary Class 1</b>
              </td>
            </tr>

          </xsl:if>
          <xsl:if test="count(Item) = 21">
            <tr>
              <td>
                <b>Main</b>
              </td>
              <td>
                <b>Auxiliary Class 1</b>
              </td>
              <td>
                <b>Auxiliary Class 2</b>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:if>
        <tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Item[not((position() - 1) mod 7)]" mode="leader"/>
        </tr>
      </xsl:template>

      <xsl:template match="Item" mode="leader">
        <td>
          <b><xsl:value-of select="Description"/>:&#160;</b>
          <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
          <br/>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::Item[position() &lt;= 6 and position() mod 2]"/>
        </td>
      </xsl:template>

      <xsl:template match="Item">
        <b><xsl:value-of select="Description"/>:&#160;</b>
        <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::Item[1]" mode="follower"/>
        <xsl:if test="position() != 3">
          <br/>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:template>

      <xsl:template match="Item" mode="follower">
        <xsl:text> / </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
      </xsl:template>
```

This seems to work well. But I wanted the "description" labels only on the first column and I can't work out how to remove it from the other column(s):

[image: Remove additional description labels]

I continued to try and apply what was suggested (inline tables) and the code is simpler:

```
          <xsl:template match="StudentItems">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Item[not((position() - 1) mod 7)]" mode="leader"/>
          </xsl:template>

          <xsl:template match="Item" mode="leader">
            <table cellpadding="2" style="float:left;">
            <tr>
              <td>
                <xsl:choose>
                  <xsl:when test="position() = 1">Main </xsl:when>
                  <xsl:when test="position() = 2">Auxiliary Class 1 </xsl:when>
                  <xsl:otherwise>Auxiliary Class 2 </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <b>
                  <xsl:value-of select="Description"/>:&#160;
                </b>
                <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::Item[position() &lt;= 6 and position() mod 2]"/>
            </table>   
          </xsl:template>

          <xsl:template match="Item">
            <tr>
              <td>
                <b>
                  <xsl:value-of select="Description"/>:&#160;
                </b>
                <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::Item[1]" mode="follower"/>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </xsl:template>

          <xsl:template match="Item" mode="follower">
            <xsl:text> / </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
          </xsl:template>
```

This seems simpler. Thanks. But I still have two issues:

1. I don't want the heading row if there is only 7 items (or less) in the StudentItems list.
2. I don't want to add "descriptions" for the second or third tables.

Can this be done?

Comment: I would suggest you try creating a table for each group of 7, and display them inline. I think that would be much easier to implement.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean about inline tables. Sorry.

Comment: See (for example): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11690223/html-two-tables-side-by-side

Comment: OK, I can see now how to place two tables side by side (or three) by using the `style="float: left;"` syntax. Thanks. But can you advise me on the changes to the template script? It is not clear to me how to revise it. Sorry. :(

Comment: I have made changes to the templates. New code in the topic. Just a couple of questions as indicated still.

Comment: Apparently, I misunderstood what you want. I thought you wanted to put each name in a cell. Apparently, you want two names per cell (except in the first row)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102029/discussion-between-andrew-truckle-and-michael-hor257k).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have presented this as an extension of [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35063212/3016153) - and my first answer was an adaption of the answer I gave there. However, the nature of the problem has changed significantly, and I thought it might be better to look at it with fresh eyes.

This solution may not be as "clever" as the other one - but to me it seems a lot more straightforward.

```
<xsl:template match="StudentItems">
    <table border="1" width="80%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th/>
                <xsl:for-each select="Item[contains('|1|8|15|', concat('|', position(), '|'))]">
                    <th colspan="2">
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="position() = 1">Main</xsl:when>
                            <xsl:when test="position() = 2">Auxiliary Class 1</xsl:when>
                            <xsl:when test="position() = 3">Auxiliary Class 2</xsl:when>
                        </xsl:choose>
                    </th>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th><xsl:value-of select="Item[1]/Description"/></th>
                <xsl:for-each select="Item[contains('|1|8|15|', concat('|', position(), '|'))]">
                    <td colspan="2"><xsl:value-of select="Name"/></td>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th><xsl:value-of select="Item[2]/Description"/></th>
                <xsl:for-each select="Item[contains('|2|3|9|10|16|17|', concat('|', position(), '|'))]">
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="Name"/></td>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th><xsl:value-of select="Item[4]/Description"/></th>
                <xsl:for-each select="Item[contains('|4|5|11|12|18|19|', concat('|', position(), '|'))]">
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="Name"/></td>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th><xsl:value-of select="Item[6]/Description"/></th>
                <xsl:for-each select="Item[contains('|6|7|13|14|20|21|', concat('|', position(), '|'))]">
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="Name"/></td>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</xsl:template>
```

The result here is a **single** table, rendered as:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I will try it later today. I will see if I can adjust it as I ideally want one column and "name / name" as opposed to 2. I will update you. I do agree it is simpler to read. Just got to learn it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I would do something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="StudentItems">
    <table border="1" style="display:inline;">
        <tr>
            <td>&#160;</td>
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="Item[contains('1,2,4,6', position())]">
            <tr>
                <th><xsl:value-of select="Description"/></th>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Item[position()mod 7 = 1]" mode="leader"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Item" mode="leader">
    <table border="1" style="display:inline;">
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="position() = 1">Main </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="position() = 2">Auxiliary Class 1 </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>Auxiliary Class 2 </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </th>
        </tr>   
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><xsl:value-of select="Name"/></td>
        </tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::Item[position() &lt;= 6 and position() mod 2]"/>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Item">
    <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="Name"/></td>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::Item[1]" mode="follower"/>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Item" mode="follower">
    <td><xsl:value-of select="Name"/></td>
</xsl:template>
```

Applied to the following test input:

```
<StudentItems>
   <Item>
      <Name>Name 1</Name>
      <Description>Bible Reading</Description>
   </Item>
   <Item>
      <Name>Name 2</Name>
      <Description>Initial Call</Description>
   </Item>
   <Item>
      <Name>Name 3</Name>
      <Description>Initial Call</Description>
   </Item>
   <Item>
      <Name>Name 4</Name>
      <Description>Return Visit</Description>
   </Item>
   <Item>
      <Name>Name 5</Name>
      <Description>Return Visit</Description>
   </Item>
   <Item>
      <Name>Name 6</Name>
      <Description>Bible Study</Description>
   </Item>
   <Item>
      <Name>Name 7</Name>
      <Description>Bible Study</Description>
   </Item>
   <Item>
      <Name>Name 8</Name>
      <Description>Bible Reading</Description>
   </Item>
   <Item>
      <Name>Name 9</Name>
      <Description>Initial Call</Description>
   </Item>
   <Item>
      <Name>Name 10</Name>
      <Description>Initial Call</Description>
   </Item>
   <Item>
      <Name>Name 11</Name>
      <Description>Return Visit</Description>
   </Item>
   <Item>
      <Name>Name 12</Name>
      <Description>Return Visit</Description>
   </Item>
   <Item>
      <Name>Name 13</Name>
      <Description>Bible Study</Description>
   </Item>
   <Item>
      <Name>Name 14</Name>
      <Description>Bible Study</Description>
   </Item>
   <Item>
      <Name>Name 15</Name>
      <Description>Bible Reading</Description>
   </Item>
   <Item>
      <Name>Name 16</Name>
      <Description>Initial Call</Description>
   </Item>
   <Item>
      <Name>Name 17</Name>
      <Description>Initial Call</Description>
   </Item>
   <Item>
      <Name>Name 18</Name>
      <Description>Return Visit</Description>
   </Item>
   <Item>
      <Name>Name 19</Name>
      <Description>Return Visit</Description>
   </Item>
   <Item>
      <Name>Name 20</Name>
      <Description>Bible Study</Description>
   </Item>
   <Item>
      <Name>Name 21</Name>
      <Description>Bible Study</Description>
   </Item>
</StudentItems>
```

The result (rendered) is:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I will look at this over next two days.